# Navigation problem in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, multiplatform

I am creating an application with Kotlin Multiplatform using Compose Multiplatform, I am using the Voyager library to do the navigation of the application.

I have a BottomNavigationBar configured and it works correctly and inside the main Tab I have a button that navigates to a Screen, the problem is that when I navigate to the Screen, it replaces the Tab and if I click again on the BottomNavigationBar to go back to that main screen, it does nothing.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun App() {

    val tabs = listOf(HomeTab, MapsTab)

    MaterialTheme {

        TabNavigator(tab = HomeTab,
            tabDisposable = {

                TabDisposable(
                    navigator = it,
                    tabs = tabs
                )
            }
        ) {
            Scaffold(topBar = {
                TopAppBar(title = {
                    Text(text = it.current.options.title)
                })
            }, bottomBar = {
                BottomNavigation {
                    tabs.forEach { tab ->
                        TabNavigationItem(tab)
                    }
                }
            }, content = {
                CurrentTab()
            })
        }
    }

}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun RowScope.TabNavigationItem(tab: Tab) {
    val tabNavigator = LocalTabNavigator.current

    BottomNavigationItem(
        selected = tabNavigator.current.key == tab.key,
        onClick = {
            tabNavigator.current = tab
        },
        icon = {
            tab.options.icon?.let { safePainter ->
                Icon(
                    painter = safePainter,
                    contentDescription = tab.options.title
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

```kotlin
object HomeTab : Tab {

    override val options: TabOptions
        @Composable
        get() {
            val icon = rememberVectorPainter(Icons.Default.Home)

            return remember {
                TabOptions(
                    index = 0u,
                    title = "Home",
                    icon = icon
                )
            }
        }

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        Navigator(screen = HomeScreen()) { navigator ->
            SlideTransition(navigator = navigator)
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class HomeScreen : Screen {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {

        val navigator = LocalNavigator.currentOrThrow

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {

            Button(onClick = {
                navigator.push(DetailScreen())
            }) {
                Text("Go to detail")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I understand why this is happening, and that is that when I am in DetailScreen, the Tab is still the same, so it tries to make CurrentTab() the same as it already is, but I don't know how to change this behaviour.